# ILogger sink for Azure Serverless Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am injecting `ILogger` into my Azure functions, and in my `host.json` I have the following:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I then log as below:

```
public class EnrollmentFunctions
{
    private readonly ILogger<AttestationFunctions> logger;

    public EnrollmentFunctions(ILogger<AttestationFunctions> log)
    {
        logger = log;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Enroll(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "enroll")] HttpRequest req)
    {
         logger.LogInformation("Requesting attestation of device name {deviceName}.", req.Query["deviceName"]);
    }
}
```

However no logs are logged as below - appreciate pointers as to what I am doing wrong and where I would see my logs please.

[image: Live Metrics]

Comment: Can you show your code that uses ILogger?

Answer (score 0):

*I've followed the below work around to achieve the desired results as described:*

I've used generalized logging in my function project using Visual studio and included both **ILogger** and **TelemetryClient** in a class `Genlog.cs`

**Genlog.cs**

```cs
  public class Genlog
    {
        public Genlog(ILogger<Genlog> logger, TelemetryClient telemetry)
        {
            Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            Telemetry = telemetry ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(telemetry));
        }

        public void testlog(string mylog)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("TestCustomInformationLog:" + mylog);
            Telemetry.TrackTrace("TestCustomTraceLog: " + mylog, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
            Telemetry.TrackException(new Exception(""));            
        }

        public ILogger<Genlog> Logger { get; }
        public TelemetryClient Telemetry { get; }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
#Adding configuring service of Genlog in startup.cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<Genlog>();
}
```

**Function.cs**

```cs
  public class Function1
    {
        private readonly Genlog genlog;
        public Function1(Genlog genlog)
        {
            this.genlog = genlog ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(genlog));
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            # Using Both Ilogger & Telemetry logger in same class.
            genlog.testlog("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
            genlog.testlog(responseMessage);
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```

#### Result

[image]

**Published to `Azure` to check & retrieve logs:**

[image]