# Azure Function Isolated: simple way to access ILogger in all classes?

Tags: c#, azure, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am using Azure Functions in Isolated mode, .NET 7.

I am able to inject a logger into my functions pretty easily by simply adding an ILogger to the constructor of my functions and having the logging config setup in host.json file.

I can also inject an ILogger to any class, if I make that class an Interface, and inject the interface in my startup method.

However, I find this cumbersome, as often I don't need an interface, so I am making an Interface just for a single class to implement it, and sometimes I want to instantiate my object with property values, and then the DI won't work in those cases.

Is there a simple way/design pattern that allows me to have a single static or Singleton method Logger.Log("Message") from anywhere in my entire solution?

Comment: Can you post an example? I don't see why you'd need superfluent interfaces.

Comment: Is this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337017/ilogger-sink-for-azure-serverless-functions/74361205#74361205) works for you?

Comment: "I can also inject an ILogger to any class, if I make that class an Interface." Are you sure you need to do that? You can register a type with DI without having an interface.

Comment: @Jahnavi, thanks for the reply. This example is still injecting into the constructor. How can I write to a log without needing to inject an instance to a class? I want to have a simple static logging class I can call from anywhere, like LoggerHelper.Log().... where LoggerHelper is a static class

Comment: @ScottHannen, thanks, I just realized that AddSingleton() etc all take concrete classes with no Interface param and will behave the same way. That's really great and allows me to skip the Interfaces when I really don't need them. I always thought DI was about injecting implementations, so this may be a more recent advancement? In any case, I'm still not sure how to make a static logging class that can take adventure of the Logger inside of Isolated Proc Azure Functions without having to DI my logger every single time. I'd really like to just have a static method like Logger.Log("..")

Comment: It's always been that way. The trouble is that so much documentation includes the interface, and then all the code you see everywhere has the interface.